# Download raw data in Joomla component

Tags: joomla

I have written a Joomla component which is working well. I now want to add a button to an admin list view that when clicked automatically starts a CSV download of only the items selected in the list.

I'm OK with the model logic, the problem I've got is passing the selected cids or presenting raw output without the template.

If I use JToolBar's `appendButton` function to add a 'Link' type button, then I can send the user to a URL with 'format=raw', but I can't send information about which items were checked.

If I use `JToolBarHelper::custom` to add a custom list button, then I can send the information about which buttons were checked, but I can't send `format=raw`

As far as I can see there are two solutions, but I don't know how to implement either of them. Option one would be to force templateless raw output without a URL parameter of `format=raw`. Option two would be to set a hidden variable with `format=raw` in the admin form.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Take a look at how this is done in com_banners. It's the easiest example if you just need to do one.

Comment: I assume you're referring to the tracks view in com_banners. This isn't what I need because you can't select which items you want at a fine grained level (you can only filter). I have a list view and I want to allow admin to select items and only download those items. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What I think you need to do is to define a document type (the way there is for html, feed, json and others, but of the format you want. Then just like you build view.html.php or view.feed.php you build view.csv.php but make it so that is supports filters. I think it will be not that hard since you have the filters in the state.

Comment: I'm happy with raw, I don't think need a new document type. Problem is unless you have format=raw in the query string, Joomla will display the raw view, but it will encase it with the whole template.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this as follows:

I added this hidden field to the admin form

```
<input type="hidden" name="format" value="html" />
```

Then subclassed `JToolbarButtonStandard` overriding the `_getCommand` with

```
protected function _getCommand($name,$task,$list)
{
    JHtml::_('behavior.framework');
    $message = JText::_('JLIB_HTML_PLEASE_MAKE_A_SELECTION_FROM_THE_LIST');
    $message = addslashes($message);

    if ($list)
    {
        $cmd = "if (document.adminForm.boxchecked.value==0){alert('$message');}else{document.getElementById('adminForm').format.value='raw'; Joomla.submitbutton('$task')}";
    }
    else
    {
        $cmd = "document.getElementById('adminForm').format.value='raw'; Joomla.submitbutton('$task')";
    }

    return $cmd;
}
```

So that when the button was clicked it changed the `format` parameter from `html` to `raw`.

I'm not going to mark this as solved in case anyone has any better ideas